# ActiveAndroid got error, no such table

Tags: android, orm, activeandroid, android-database

My Manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".AppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="mydb.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Here AppClass:

```
public class AppClass extends Application {
public static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
    context = getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

Model:

```
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Book extends Model {

    @Column(name = "Author")
    public String author;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    public String title;

    public Book() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Save book and retrieve that:

```
 Book b = new Book();
        b.title = "TheFaultInOurStar";
        b.author = "JohnGreen";
        b.save();

 ArrayList<Book> books = new Select().all().from(Book.class).execute();
 Log.e("Log", "SizeOfBooks:" + books.size());
```

but when run the app i got this error:

```
 Error inserting Title=TheFaultInOurStar  Author=JohnGreen rolling Id=null
                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Books (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Books(Title,Author,Id) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

why Id field add to table schema? 
i increase AA_DB_VERSION in manifest but error still remain. 
even app in fresh run on other emulator and mobile phone got that error again.

where is problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try put this meta-data inside application tag on your AndroidManifest.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="AA_MODELS"
     android:value="com.yourpackage.yourmodeldir.Book" />
```

Or if it doesn't fix the problem. Try to uninstall your app then reinstall it.

Comment: still not work, and get this error: no such table: Books (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ALL * FROM Books

Comment: I think all your code is right. Have you checked android:name=".AppClass" correctly references to your Application class?